# Error in solving two equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I am trying to solve these two equations:
$$x'(l)=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{r_0^4-1}{r(l)^4-1}}}{r(l)}$$
$$r'(l)=\frac{\sqrt{r(l)^4-r_0^4}}{r(l)}$$
with initial conditions as r[0]=r_0 and x[0]=0. When I try to use Mathematica to solve these two equations I get an empty result. The code that I used here is:
`DSolve[{x'[l] == (1/r[l] Sqrt[(r0^4 - 1)/(r[l]^4 - 1)]),    r'[l] == Sqrt[r[l]^4 - r0^4]/r[l], x[0] == 0, r[0] == r0},     {x[l], r[l]}, l]`
Any help in this regard would be deeply appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking for a real solution? `r[l]>r0>1`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, Yes I have added that in $Assumptions as well.

Comment: Would be helpful if you show your assumptions!

Comment: How about solving for $r(l)$ in the second and then substituting that solution into the first.  When I did that, ver 13 returns the (unevaluated) integral form of $x(l)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second equation does not depend on x, solve it first separately. I restrict r0 > 0.

```
(eqs = {x'[l] == (1/r[l] Sqrt[(r0^4 - 1)/(r[l]^4 - 1)]), 
r'[l] == Sqrt[r[l]^4 - r0^4]/r[l], x[0] == 0, 
r[0] == r0}) // TableForm

dsol = DSolve[eqs[[2]], r, l]

Solve[(r[0] /. dsol[[1]]) == r0 && r0 > 0, C[1], Reals]

(*   {}   *)

sol1 = Solve[(r[0] /. dsol[[2]]) == r0 && r0 > 0, C[1], Reals] // 
  ToRadicals

rsol[r0_] = r /. dsol[[2]] /. (sol1[[1]] // FullSimplify[#, r0 > 0] &)

(*   Function[{l}, (
     E^(1/2 (-2 l - 2 Log[r0])) Sqrt[E^(4 l + 4 Log[r0]) + r0^4])/Sqrt[2]]   *)

Plot[rsol[1/2][l], {l, 0, 5}]

neweq = eqs[[1]] /. r -> rsol[r0] // 
  FullSimplify[#, r0 > 0 && l > 0] &

xsol[r0_] = x /. Flatten@DSolve[neweq, x, l]

limx0 = Limit[xsol[r0][l], l -> 0, Direction -> -1]

sol2 = Solve[0 == limx0 && 0 < r0, C[1], Reals, Method -> Reduce]

(*   Solve::fexp: Warning: Solve used FunctionExpand to transform the system.....   C[1] -> ConditionalExpression[...   *)

xsolf[r0_][l_] = 
  xsol[r0][l] /. (First@sol2 // FullSimplify[#, 0 < r0 < 1] &)

(*   (Sqrt[1 - r0^2] EllipticK[1/2 - r0/(1 + r0^2)])/(
Sqrt[2] r0) + ((-1 + r0^4) AppellF1[1/2, 3/4, 1/2, 3/2, 
 1/2 (2 - r0^4 - r0^4 Cosh[4 l]), (-2 + r0^4 + r0^4 Cosh[4 l])/(
 2 (-1 + r0^4))] Cosh[2 l] Csch[4 l] Sqrt[-((
 r0^4 Sinh[2 l]^2)/(-1 + r0^4))])/(Sqrt[2] r0 (r0^4 Cosh[2 l]^2)^(
 1/4) Sqrt[((-1 + r0^4) Sech[2 l])/(-2 + r0^4 + r0^4 Cosh[4 l])])   *)

Manipulate[
Plot[Evaluate[xsolf[r0][l]], {l, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 11, 
MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotRange -> {0, 10}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 25], {{r0, 1/2}, 0, 1, 1/20}, 
ContinuousAction -> False, ControlType -> Setter]
```

For r0 -> 1, xsol gets imaginary for increasing lower l.

Test

```
eqs[[2]] /. r -> rsol[r0] // FullSimplify[#, r0 > 0 && l > 0] &     (*   True   *)

(eqs[[1]] /. r -> rsol[r0] // 
FullSimplify[#, 0 < r0 < 1 && l > 0] &) /. x -> xsolf[r0] // 
FullSimplify[#, 0 < r0 < 1 && l > 0] &   (*   True   *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Answer. I just have an issue using this code in Mathematica 11. I am not getting any answer beyond this line : ```limx0 = Limit[xsol[r0][l], l -> 0, Direction -> -1]``` Maybe it works fine with the latest version of Mathematica.

Comment: I am working with version 8.0. If your version can't do the Limit, try `ser = Series[xsol[r0][l], {l, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> r0 > 0] // 
   Normal // FullSimplify[#, r0 > 0] & ` and then `ser /. l -> 0 `  or `Limit[ser, l -> 0] ` to get the `limx0 ` .

Comment: It works perfectly now. Many many Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I  cannot comprehend the result (Mathematica v12.2): Shouldn't `D[  Function[{l}, (
     E^(1/2 (-2 l - 2 Log[r0])) Sqrt[E^(4 l + 4 Log[r0]) + r0^4])/Sqrt[2]][l],l]` evaluate to `eqs[[2]]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann , yes it does. This is my `rsol[r0][l] `  and as i showed in the Test  `eqs[[2]] /. r -> rsol[r0] // 
 FullSimplify[#, r0 > 0 && l > 0] &     (*True*) `

Comment: @Akku14 Thank you for the feedback. Because I couldn't evaluate your code I cut&pasted your `rsol[r0][l] ` (`Function[{l}, (
     E^(1/2 (-2 l - 2 Log[r0])) Sqrt[E^(4 l + 4 Log[r0]) + r0^4])/Sqrt[2]] `) from the comment. Derivative evaluates to  `(E^-l (-1 + E^(4 l)) r0^3)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(1 + E^(4 l)) r0^4])` on Mathematica v12.2

Answer (score 2):

Dividing both odes eliminates parameter l and gives a new ode  `x'[r]==...` , which can be solved symbolically:

```
X = Values@DSolve[{x'[r] == (1/r  Sqrt[(r0^4 - 1)/(r ^4 - 1)])/(Sqrt[r ^4 - r0^4]/r )  }, x, r][[1, 1]]

(*Function[{r}, (5 r r0^4 Sqrt[(-1 + r0^4)/(-1 + r^4)]AppellF1[1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 5/4, r^4, r^4/r0^4])/(Sqrt[r^4 - r0^4] (5 r0^4 AppellF1[1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 5/4, r^4, r^4/r0^4] 
+ 2 r^4 (AppellF1[5/4, 1/2, 3/2, 9/4, r^4, r^4/r0^4] +r0^4 AppellF1[5/4, 3/2,1/2, 9/4, r^4, r^4/r0^4]))) + C[1]]*)
```

Adjustment to initial conditions `X[r0]==0` remains open

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Answer. Actually, I needed the answers in the form of x[l] and r[l] explicitly, that's why I didn't divide both odes.